# How to regex match words with/without hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having a lot of difficulties matching strings in JavaScript using regex. Problem is when I match strings like "assistant-attorney" with "attorney" it returns true. I cannot ignore/forbid hyphens, as I also want to be able to match "assistant-attorney" with "assistant-attorney" and also get true. Can't figure out if I should use word boundaries, or check if string does not start with white space or hyphen.

What I have so far is this:

```
([^-])(attorney)
```

Here's a test:
https://www.regextester.com/?fam=121381

Hope anyone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to match exactly - the input string and the desired matched output, currently it is not clear enough.

Comment: I want to match only the words, not the whitespace. And I want to make "attorney" match only "attorney", not "assistant-attorney". And gain, I also want to make "assistant-attorney" match "assistant-attorney". Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple *Negative Lookbehind* group could do the trick

`(?<!-)attorney`

> Negative Lookbehind `(?<!-)` Assert that the Regex below does not match

##### UPDATE

As @MonkeyZeus said, the first version failed on `attorneys` and `fakewordwithattorneyinit`

The new regexp is using negative lookbehind and negative lookahead look like this :

`\b(?<!-)attorney(?!-)\b` if you want to match in all string
[image]

`^\b(?<!-)attorney(?!-)\b` if you want to match "line begins with term"

https://regex101.com/r/FToha6/1

Comment: Great answer and solution. Works perfectly, and I think the lookahead/lookback solution is the cleanest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use word boundaries and enhance them with additional requirements:

```
(?<=^|[^-])\battorney\b(?=[^-]|$)
```

- `(?<=^|[^-])` - assert that behind me is the start of a line or is not a hyphen
- `\b` - word boundary
- `attorney` - the search term
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=[^-]|$)` - assert that in front of me is not a hyphen or is the end of a line

attorney - https://regex101.com/r/HCRKWi/1

assistant-attorney - https://regex101.com/r/2tvU1n/1

Comment: Works perfectly! And great answer, thanks a lot!